# React Native - Fetching data and saving it

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm creating an app for tourism, and all my data is coming from an API. I'm getting it from the fetch method:

```
    constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      fetching: false,
      api: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({ fetching: true })

    api.getMonuments().then(res => {
      this.setState({
        api: res,
        fetching: false
      })
    })

  }
```

but here is a big problem. If the user doesn't have Internet he cant use the app... What I want is to save the data. Everytime the user starts the app if there is internet he fetch the data and save it and if there is no internet he uses the data that were saved on the phone... How can I accomplish that?

I suppose I have to use AsyncStorage but I don't know how. Another problem is that the images that I get from the API is just a path and what I would like to do, is to download them and save them. Basically I want the app to be functional even when the user has no internet.

Here is a [sample of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6zBD.jpg) I'm getting from the API.

Hope you can help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: So to save an object (e.g. your API's returned JSON) you can simply do this: `await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', someJson)`. For saving images, it's difficult as you'd be saving the raw bytes. Using the FileSystem would be better -> https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs or even https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cached-image

Comment: If you are using redux then you can use redux persist: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist